# Why is Python's built-in sum much slower than manual summation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my simple code example:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
s = 0
for i in range(1000000):
    s += i
t1 = time.time()

print(s, t1 - t0)

t0 = time.time()
s = sum(i for i in range(1000000))
t1 = time.time()

print(s, t1 - t0)
```

On my computer (with Python 3.8) it prints:

```
499999500000 0.22901296615600586
499999500000 1.6930372714996338
```

So, doing `+=` a million times is 7 times faster than calling `sum`? That is really unexpected. What is it doing?

---

**Edit:** I foolishly allowed a debugger to attach to the process and interfere with my measurements, which was in the end the cause of the slowness. With the debugger out, the measurements are no longer so unpredictable. As some of the answers are clearly showing, what I observed shuold not happen.

Comment: Is it possible that the second version constructs the entire list in order to iterate it?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.9, and for me the second version is twice as fast as the first.  But the second has two levels of loop (the implicit loop from `sum`, and the explicit loop with `for`).  Eliminating the unnecessary `for` loop triples the speed:  `sum(range(1000000))`.

Comment: @vonludi: It does not. It is a generator expression. But yes, that seems to be causing the problem. For some reason, the generator is very slow.

Comment: I got `0.2744462490081787` for first expression and `0.16035890579223633` for second. Try using `sum` with an already constructed list.

Comment: `sum(range(1000000))` is even faster: you don't need to iterate over the `range` object with a generator expression in order for `sum` to have an iterable.

Comment: Using either Python 3.7 or Python 3.8, I also get the generator version being twice as fast as the loop, and `sum(range(...))` being twice as fast again as the generator.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce this observation with a more reliable technique like with `timeit` or similar, you should also include some details of your system, how you did obtain your Python and whether you can replicate your results with different Python versions.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use `timeit` for proper benchmarking and to make it easy to also compare different Python versions, let's run this in Docker containers:

## so62514160.py

```
N = 1000000

def m1():
    s = 0
    for i in range(N):
        s += i

def m2():
    s = sum(i for i in range(N))

def m3():
    s = sum(range(N))
```

## so62514160bench.sh

```
for image in python:2.7 python:3.6 python:3.7 python:3.8; do
    for fun in m1 m2 m3; do
        echo -n "$image" "$fun "
        docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app -w /app -e PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 "$image" python -m timeit -s 'import so62514160 as s' "s.$fun()"
    done
done
```

## results on my machine:

```
python:2.7 m1 10 loops, best of 3:  43.5 msec per loop
python:2.7 m2 10 loops, best of 3:  39.6 msec per loop
python:2.7 m3 100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 msec per loop
python:3.6 m1 10 loops, best of 3:  41.9 msec per loop
python:3.6 m2 10 loops, best of 3:  46 msec per loop
python:3.6 m3 100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 msec per loop
python:3.7 m1 5 loops, best of 5:   45 msec per loop
python:3.7 m2 5 loops, best of 5:   40.7 msec per loop
python:3.7 m3 20 loops, best of 5:  17.3 msec per loop
python:3.8 m1 5 loops, best of 5:   48.2 msec per loop
python:3.8 m2 5 loops, best of 5:   44.6 msec per loop
python:3.8 m3 10 loops, best of 5:  19.2 msec per loop
```

## plot

[image]

Comment: Nice way of demonstrating how to do proper benchmarking!

Comment: Why's it "best of" instead of averaging, and using different number of loops?

Comment: Does this show that python 3.8 is slightly slower than the previous versions? Or are these differences too small to be significant?

Comment: This post is also not "answering" the "why" question at all for the upvotes it's getting, only showing more benchmarks; why m3's faster remains to be explained.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Not really, it is skipping the explicit looping. You can easily check with `dis` that you are getting a simpler bytecode with `m3()`.

Comment: @norok2 This information is neither in your nor this answer - and the question is *why* it is happening, not *is it* happening. Admittedly the original question doesn't include `sum(range())`, but all the answers are still about "this is what is is" not "this is why it is"

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Probably, it gets a lot less interesting to discuss the *why* when your observation come from *weak methodology*, so that the actual behavior is *not* surprising, and the reason seems quite obvious. Anyway, I updated my answer to incude some bytecode to support the timing observations.

Comment: These are really interesting results. Thanks for the analysis. I am afraid my mistery is still not solved, though. I initially useed PYthon 3.8.0. Then I installed Python 3.8.3 and the results are now much worse than before! I repeated the tests using `timeit` with no difference. It takes 10 seconds per loop for the `sum(generator)` option in 3.8.3! I am using Windows 7 on an old PC and 32-bit Python. That may be related, I'll have to test different combinations.

Comment: @zvone can you check with other Python versions too?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The different number of loops is timeit figuring out how much it needs to do for a statistically significant result.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, probably your observation does not generalize well to other systems, as your way of measuring is quite unreliable because it is susceptible to fluctuation in performances that are bound to be dominated by how your OS reacts to the fluctuating system load at the time of measurement.
You should use `timeit` or something similar.

For example, this are the timings I get on Python 3.6 in a virtual environment (Google Colab) (which seems to be quite reproducible across the other answers):

```
import numba as nb


def sum_loop(n):
    result = 0
    for x in range(n):
        result += x
    return result


sum_loop_nb = nb.jit(sum_loop)
sum_loop_nb.__name__ = 'sum_loop_nb'


def sum_analytical(n):
    return n * (n - 1) // 2


def sum_list(n):
    return sum([x for x in range(n)])


def sum_gen(n):
    return sum(x for x in range(n))


def sum_range(n):
    return sum(range(n))


sum_loop_nb(10)  # to trigger compilation


funcs = sum_analytical, sum_loop, sum_loop_nb, sum_gen, sum_list, sum_range


n = 1000000
for func in funcs:
    print(func.__name__, func(n))
    %timeit func(n)
# sum_analytical 499999500000
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 222 ns per loop
# sum_loop 499999500000
# 10 loops, best of 3: 55.6 ms per loop
# sum_loop_nb 499999500000
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 196 ns per loop
# sum_gen 499999500000
# 10 loops, best of 3: 51.7 ms per loop
# sum_list 499999500000
# 10 loops, best of 3: 68.4 ms per loop
# sum_range 499999500000
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
```

It is unlikely that you will observe much different timings across different Python versions.

The `sum_analytical()` and `sum_loop_nb()` versions have been included just for fun and are not analyzed further.
The `sum_list()` is also behaving quite differently from the rest, as it is creating a large, largely unnecessary, object for the computation, and it is also not analyzed further.

---

The reason for these different timings is in the bytecode produced by the considered versions of the functions, of course. In particular, from `sum_loop()` through `sum_range()` one gets progressively simpler code:

```
import dis

funcs = sum_loop, sum_gen, sum_range
for func in funcs:
    print(func.__name__)
    print(dis.dis(func))
    print()

# sum_loop
#   2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
#               2 STORE_FAST               1 (result)

#   3           4 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 30)
#               6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
#               8 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
#              10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              12 GET_ITER
#         >>   14 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
#              16 STORE_FAST               2 (x)

#   4          18 LOAD_FAST                1 (result)
#              20 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
#              22 INPLACE_ADD
#              24 STORE_FAST               1 (result)
#              26 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
#         >>   28 POP_BLOCK

#   5     >>   30 LOAD_FAST                1 (result)
#              32 RETURN_VALUE
# None

# sum_gen
#   9           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
#               2 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7f86d67c49c0, file "<ipython-input-4-9519b0039c88>", line 9>)
#               4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('sum_gen.<locals>.<genexpr>')
#               6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
#               8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
#              10 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
#              12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              14 GET_ITER
#              16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              20 RETURN_VALUE
# None

# sum_range
#  13           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
#               2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
#               4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
#               6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#               8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              10 RETURN_VALUE
# None
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted unless others offer a better _explanation_ (not more benchmarks); I'd also point readers to check comments, which include some further info.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found an answer myself, but it bring up another question.

So, this is much faster:

```
t0 = time.time()
s = sum(range(1000000))
t1 = time.time()

print(s, t1 - t0)
```

The result is:

```
499999500000 0.05099987983703613
```

So, `sum` is faster than `+=`, as expected, but the generator expression `(i for i in range(n))` is much slower than anything else.

I must say that this is also quite surprising.

Comment: it's probably because of sum's implementation over a generator. Have you tried with a list instead `sum([i for i in range(n)])` to see what it yields?

Comment: this is not how we benchmark code btw, take a look at `timeit` module

Comment: this is interesting indeed. I would say that the expression `(i for i in range(n))` is somehow what you are invited to write right?

Comment: Also, if I am not mistaken, `range(n)` already gives you a generator... so you are going over a generator to recreate it. Seems a bit wasteful. Maybe `sum(range(n))` is the fastest because of the low level implementation of `sum`.

Comment: Generators are designed to require minimum memory, not provide speed.

Comment: @jpnadas True, but this is a simplified version of what I had in my real code, where I did some operation on `i` before summing it up. BTW, `sum([i for i in range(1000000)])` is much faster than `sum(i for i in range(1000000))`!

Comment: fair enough @zvone ... so in the real implementation, which is faster, `sum([operations(i) for i in my_list])` or the `+=` solution?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov A good point, but I get the same results with `timeit`.

Comment: @chepner True, but the slowness I see is too bad for that explanation. OTOH, no one else seems to be able to reproduce my numbers, so it seems be about my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I get different numbers

```
python3 main.py
499999500000 0.0832064151763916
499999500000 0.03934478759765625
```

And from this code

```
import time

to0 = []
to1 = []

for i in range(1000):
    t0 = time.time()
    s = 0
    for i in range(1000000):
        s += i
    t1 = time.time()

    to0.append(t1 - t0)

    t0 = time.time()
    s = sum(i for i in range(1000000))
    t1 = time.time()

    to1.append(t1 - t0)


print(sum(to0)/len(to0))
print(sum(to1)/len(to1))
```

I get

```
0.07862246823310852
0.0318267240524292
```

Try updating your python all this is run on Python 3.7.3

Comment: Well, the thing is my Python is newer that yours! Maybe it is a bug which was introduced in 3.8.

Comment: With python 3.8.2 I get 0.09662985801696777
0.03805732727050781